# Real time data analysis, any tools or package inside ROS?

Tags: ros, real-time, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

Im wondering is there any tools or some packages inside ROS that permit real-time data analysis. I have used ROS in our mobile device , but I need to perform some online (real-time) analysis of the datas provided by my ROS nodes. Like speed profiles, distances to some object or obstacles , would like to be collected in long period of time, stored in some location and than in real-time (on-line) make them available for analysis. Is there any help inside ROS or do I need some additional Hardware and Software outside ROS??

Any help or comment would be welcome

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62157/real-time-data-analysis,-any-tools-or-package-inside-ros?/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are tools like [rqt_plot](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt_plot) for realtime plotting. And [rqt_bag](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt_bag) for recording and playback of generic data, which itself has plugins for viewing various types of data.

If you have more specific requirements please clarify your question.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-05-06**:
Well im referring to real time hardware also and software. So mean to use ROS for real time application. Is that possible??